# cannot resolve method getElevation()

Tags: java

I'm making a project in Java that's a basic GPS process. It has a point class that is the current location, shown below;

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Point {

private static final double MIN_LONGITUDE = -180.0;
private static final double MAX_LONGITUDE = 180.0;
private static final double MIN_LATITUDE = -90.0;
private static final double MAX_LATITUDE = 90.0;
private static final double MEAN_EARTH_RADIUS = 6.371009e+6;

// TODO: Define fields for time, longitude, latitude and elevation

public static ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();
public static double longitude;
public static double latitude;
public static double elevation;


// TODO: Define a constructor



public Point(ZonedDateTime timestamp, double longitude, double latitude, double elevation) {

    if( longitude < MIN_LONGITUDE || longitude > MAX_LONGITUDE || latitude < MIN_LATITUDE || latitude > MAX_LATITUDE)
        throw new GPSException("Longitude or latitude is incorrect");


    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.elevation = elevation;

}

public Point() {
    this(time, -1.54853, 53.80462, 72.5);
}

// TODO: Define getters for the fields


public static ZonedDateTime getTime() {
    return time;
}

public static double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public static double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public static double getElevation() {
    return elevation;
}

// TODO: Define a toString() method that meets requirements
public String toString() {

    return "( " + longitude + ", " + latitude + " ),  " + elevation + " )";
}
```

There is then a class called Track that is a collection of Points showing a journey.

```
class Track  {

public LinkedList<Point> Track = new LinkedList<Point>();

public void add(Object Point) {

    Track.add((Point) Point);
}


public Object get(int I) {

    return Track.get(I);

}

public Integer size() {

    int Size = Track.size();

    return Size;

}


public void readFile(String filename)
        throws IOException {

    int i = 0;

    ArrayList<String> textFile = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File(input.nextLine());

     input = new Scanner(filename);


    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String letter = input.next();
        textFile.add(i, letter);
        i++;
    }

    input.close();

    for (int j = 1; j < textFile.size(); j++) {


        ZonedDateTime times;
        double longitude = 0;
        double latitude;
        double elevation;

        String s = textFile.get(j);
        String[] half = s.split(",", 4);

        times = ZonedDateTime.parse(half[0]);
        longitude = Double.parseDouble((half[1]));
        latitude = Double.parseDouble((half[2]));
        elevation = Double.parseDouble((half[3]));

        Point point = new Point(times, longitude, latitude, elevation);

        Track.add(point);

    }

}


public String toString() {

    return "( " + Point.longitude + ", " + Point.latitude + " ), " + Point.elevation + " )";

}
```

}

```
 class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    ZonedDateTime time = Point.getTime();

    Track track1 = new Track();


    Point point1 = new Point(time, -1.54853, 53.80462, 72.5);

    track1.add(point1);

    System.out.println("\n" + track1);
    System.out.println(point1.getElevation());

    track1.get(0).getElevation();


}
```

}

The last line in main is giving me an error cannot resolve method. It seems to be caused by getElevation but I'm unsure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. I have tested the get elevation method on an actual point and it works fine.

Comment: What you are trying to do with this line `track1.get(0).getElevation()`? . You can fix by casting `((Point)track1.get(0))..getElevation()`

Comment: Welcome @Aimee `get` in class Track is returning an `Object` you can cast the get to Point (after checking its class)

Answer (score 0):

Because your call `track1.get(0)` returns an `Object` and that has not the `getElevation` method. You probably wanted to return a `Point` here

```
class Track  {
    public Object get(int I) {

        return Track.get(I);

    }
}
```

Besides that your method body does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the result of the get method: e.g.:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ZonedDateTime time = Point.getTime();
    Track track1 = new Track();
    Point point1 = new Point(time, -1.54853, 53.80462, 72.5);
    track1.add(point1);

    System.out.println("\n" + track1);
    System.out.println(point1.getElevation());

    if(track1.get(0) instanceof Point) { //Making sure we can cast the object
        (Point)(track1.get(0)).getElevation();
    }
}
```